How to modify the window's app title bar in VS Code?
The Windows app title bar swallows a lot of space in all software I want this title bar to be modified to make it smaller or somehow change its layout design because the space is not enough. How to modify the window's app title bar in VS Code?


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please use proper grammar and formatting (e.g. start the sentences with uppercase letters, and write I in uppercase), and reformat the question in the form of a question.

I just figure it out in visual studio code app, how to fix this.
In setting Windows tab options find Title Bar Style and change it to custom:


Woah that works, thanks!
